# possible ways to reduce the rendering time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highcharts, pagination

I have a web page which is constructed with **JavaScript / jQuery** , it contains huge no. of **highcharts.js** charts.

Due to that it is taking a lot of time to render all the charts at a time (7-8 sec. approx., or even more when more charts are there).

What are the ways I can reduce the rendering time or break the charts rendering using some events like scroll, etc. so that the page loads faster.

Please suggest which would be the best approach.

Comment: What do you mean by huge number of charts ?

Comment: Could you please share a link / demo to it?

Comment: https://www.highcharts.com/demo
u may see in this link about the highcharts, 
like those small charts I have hundreds of charts in m y page
(cannot share the actual web page, company policy restrictions)

Comment: why would you render thousand of charts at startup ? that makes no sense. You should render them only when they came into viewport (kind of lazy-loading)